# How to make a listView item checked after comparing some string?

Tags: c#, string, listview, compare

Can anyone help me to solve my little trouble?
I'm writing an app to work with text files. And I have GUI which contains a listView with checkboxes for each item.
I've created 2 arrays:
1st for items in listView and 2nd for all lines in a text file

```
   string[] itemInList = new string[] { listView1.Items.ToString()
   string[] lineInHosts = File.ReadAllLines(C:\Test.txt).ToArray<string>();
```

The idea is to compare all lines in "C:\Test.txt" file and all items in the listView.
If there will be a match, I want this item to be **item.Checked = true;**

PS: I've tried this -

```
        foreach (var item in itemInList)
        {
            foreach (var l in lineInHosts)
            {
                string itemName;
                ListViewItem foundItem;
                if (item == l)
                {
                    itemName = item.ToString();
                    foundItem = listView1.FindItemWithText(itemName);
                    foundItem.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no error description! Are you getting an exception? A compiler error?

Comment: there was no error and no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line should be different and the second loop is not efficient:

```
string[] itemInList =  listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>( ).Select( p => p.Text ).ToArray( );
string[] lineInHosts = File.ReadAllLines( @"C:\Test.txt" ).ToArray<string>( );

string itemName;
ListViewItem foundItem;

foreach ( var item in itemInList )
{
     if (lineInHosts.Contains(item))
     {
         itemName = item.ToString( );
         foundItem = listView1.FindItemWithText( itemName );
         foundItem.Checked = true;                    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious :)

```
 string[] itemInList = new string[] { listView1.Items.ToString()
```

There will be only one item in itemInList, and it will be called like your type.
Instead use:

```
string[] itemInList = listView1.Items.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: listView1.Items.Select(x => x.ToString()) --- There is no "Select" method.

Comment: add using System.Linq at the top

Comment: Yeah, I forgot .OfType<ListViewItem>()

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer, hope it will save someone's time

```
    foreach (var room in customerRooms)
{
 lstViewRooms.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(x =>.Text.Contains(room.Room.ToString())).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;
}
```